# How to change home directory for existing virtual ProFTPD user?

Tags: debian, ftp, user-management, proftpd, home-directory

I have my AuthUserFile located at `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.passwd`. DefaultRoot is `~`. This file currently lists a single user (username, password hash, home directory). How do I change a home directory for this virtual user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that simply modifying the file (e.g. using `sed`) is enough to make the necessary change:

```
sed -i -e 's@/old/home/path@/new/home/path@' /etc/proftpd/proftpd.passwd
```

The changes are applied after ProFTPD restart, e.g. `service proftpd restart` or another equivalent command.

It should be noted, however, that ProFTPD virtual users are linked with actual Unix users by the actual user's id (which is also stored in `proftpd.passwd`). The linked user should have the necessary permissions for the new home path. Alternatively, you may want to not only change the home path, but also link your virtual user to another actual user.

Comment: Another possibility is to use the [`ftpasswd`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/ftpasswd.html) tool, which ships with the ProFTPD source distribution, for managing entries in your `AuthUserFile`.

Comment: @Castaglia I am aware of the tool, but from the docs it seems like it has only `--change-password` option (not `--change-home`), and accepts `--home` only for newly created users. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I've filed [this ticket](https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/issues/566) for enhancing `ftpasswd` to support this use case.  Thanks!

Comment: No need to restart ProFTPD, `proftpd.passwd` home modifications are effective right away on my servers.